# Two different definitions of separable polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory

This is from *A field guide to Algebra* by Antoine Chambert Loir.

> > A polynomial $P \in K[X]$ is *separable* if and only if its roots are in an algebraic closure of $K$ are simple.

Here is another definition.

> > An irreducible polynomial $f \in F [X]$ is *separable* if $f$ has no
> >     repeated roots in a splitting field. It is called inseparable otherwise. Note that if $f$ is not necessarily irreducible, then we call $f$ separable if each of its irreducible factors is separable.

Why two different definitions?

Comment: Are they realy different? Consider an algebraic closure of the splitting field, resp. the splitting field within a given algebraic closure.

Comment: $f (X) = (X − 1)^2 (X − 2) \in \mathbb Q$. This polynomial is not seperable according to def 1 because 1 is not a simple root of $f(X)$ .

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, isn't $(x-1)^2 \in \mathbf{Q}[x]$ separable with respect to the second definition, but not with respect to the first one?

Comment: Second def. is about *irreducible* polynomials.

Comment: When a polynomial is not irreducible two definitions are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_polynomial for a good discussion of this.

Answer (score 0):

By second definition we can say every polynomial is separable and thus there is no question about inseparability. So there no further work to do. 
By the first definition, we an study both separability and inseparability as well as multiplicity and splitting field. So most of cases authors' consider the separability of irreducible polynomial as it support both the definitions....