# Question about what is a separable polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, galois-theory, definition, separable-extension

Here is the definition of separable polynomial as I understand it.

Let $K$ be a splitting field for a polynomial $f(x)\in F[x]$. If $f(x)$ is irreducible, then $f(x)$ is separable if the roots in $K$ all have multiplicity $1$. If $f(x)$ is reducible, then $f(x)$ is separable if all the irreducible factors of $f(x)$ are separable.

My question is whether the irreducible factors can share roots. For example, if $g(x)$ is a separable irreducible polynomial, then if $g(x)^2$ separable?

Comment: No, take $g(x)=x$. Then $g(x)^2=x^2$ has $x=0$ as a root with multiplicity $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems in fact two definitions of separable polynomial.

Using [the note](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/FT.pdf)(Fields and Galois Theory
J.S. Milne
), in page 33:

> Definition 2.22 A polynomial is separable if it is nonzero and satisfies the equivalent conditions on (2.21).

conditions on (2.21) is that the polynomial has only simple roots.

But there is also a footnote on this definition (in page 33 too):

> This is Bourbaki’s definition. Often, for example, in the books of Jacobson and in earlier versions of
> these notes, a polynomial  is said to be separable if each of its irreducible factors has only simple roots.

Comment: What would be the situation where these definitions give different results? Is such an example possible if $F$ is a field?

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann How about the examples at the end of the question, $g(x)^2$ where $g(x)$ is irreducible and separable?

Comment: @LutzLehmann I just copied the content from the reference and wanna to know why there’s such a situation too… maybe this could help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/297131/two-different-definitions-of-separable-polynomial

Answer (score 1):

Your stated definition of a separable polynomial is not the actual definition. A separable polynomial $f(x) \in F[x]$, $F$ a field, is one that has no repeated roots in an algebraic closure of $F$. So, if $f(x)$ has a repeated irreducible factor $g(x)$, it is not separable even if $g(x)$ is.